# javascript interval http request frequency

Tags: javascript, ajax, intervals

I am building web chat, using ajax requests with intervals.

I've been wondering what will be a legitimate interval frequency? right now i've set it to 4 seconds, but wondering if I could go for 1-2 seconds without overloading the server.

Comment: I'd use Websockets if I could.

Comment: @Vohuman, socket.io works great with fallback to regular http if websockets aren't supported

Comment: @Aroll605 Yes, socket.io is a great framework. But unfortunately it only works with NodeJS.

Comment: This question is not really related to Javascript or ajax. Its a question of the capacity of your server, and also depends on the amount of users which will be concurrently active.